# TeXnicCenter aspect ratio

Tags: texniccenter

It looks to me like my version of TeXnicCenter seems to have detected an incorrect screen size. How can I fix this?

Examples:

See the toolbar here (which I can't stretch), which makes me go to the menu to select the right output profile:
[image]
(the following example doesn't bother me because I can convert choose 'list', but I might as well have a second example)
[image]

Comment: Which version of TeXnicCenter do you use?

Comment: @Mensch 2.02 Stable (64 bit)